# What triggers a recalculation of a computed property in an async context?

Tags: vue.js, reactive-programming

I `fetch` some data from a JSON file to be processed. This asynchronous operation (the `fetch`) seems to disturb the functionality of `computed()` properties.

The code below works as expected -- data are not retrieved but hardcoded in `mounted()`. When you run the code and look at the console, you see a first computation for `filteredTags` (empty), then `allTags` are modified, which triggers a calculation of `filteredTags`.

**→ everything is as expected**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    posts: [],
    tags: {},
    allTags: {},
  },
  computed: {
    // provides an Array of tags which are selected
    filteredTags: function() {
      let t = Object.keys(this.allTags).filter(x => this.allTags[x])
      console.log("computed filteredtags: " + JSON.stringify(t))
      return t
    }
  },
  watch: {
  },
  mounted() {
    const r = '{"tag1":["/posts/premier/"],"post":["/posts/premier/","/posts/second/"]}'
    this.tags = JSON.parse(r)
    // bootstrap a tags reference where all the tags are selected
    Object.keys(this.tags).forEach(t => {
      this.$set(this.allTags, t, true)
      // this.allTags[t] = true
    });
    console.log("allTags in mounted: " + JSON.stringify(this.allTags))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="tag in filteredTags">{{tag}}</div>
</div>
```

Now the same code, but with the case where `{"tag1":["/posts/premier/"],"post":["/posts/premier/","/posts/second/"]}` is retrieved via a HTTP call:

```
<div id="app">
    <div :click="allTags[tag]=!allTags[tag]" v-for="tag in filteredTags">{{tag}}</div>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        posts: [],
        tags: {},
        allTags: {},
    },
    computed: {
        // provides an Array of tags which are selected
        filteredTags: function () {
            let t = Object.keys(this.allTags).filter(x => this.allTags[x])
            console.log("computed filteredtags: " + JSON.stringify(t))
            return t
        }
    },
    watch: {
    },
    mounted() {
        // get source tags
        fetch("tags.json")
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(r => {
            this.tags = r
            // bootstrap a tags reference where all the tags are selected
            Object.keys(this.tags).forEach(t => {
                this.$set(this.allTags, t, true)
                // this.allTags[t] = true
            });
            console.log("allTags in mounted: "+ JSON.stringify(this.allTags))
        })
    }
})
</script>
```

The output of the console is:

```
computed filteredtags: []
allTags in mounted: {"tag1":true,"post":true}
computed filteredtags: ["tag1","post"]
computed filteredtags: []
```

The first three lines are OK. **Why is there an extra recomputation of `filteredtags` at the end? And more importantly -- why is the result empty?**

Comment: If I'm not wrong you're only referencing to the result of your fetch which is only alive within the execution of the Promise. That said the data is going to get removed and therefore `this.allTags` gets emptied as well. So you have the 3 following states: empty (before fetch), full (immediately after fetch), empty (after resolved Promise).

Comment: I tried to [recreate](https://codepen.io/Hiws/pen/JjowXvp) your issue with a _very_ simple async method. However I'm not experiencing your issue. Could there be anything else conflicting?

Comment: @Aer0: yes, `r` does not exist outside of the Promise but its contents are assigned to a permanent property (`this.tags`).

Comment: @Hiws: this is the whole page, verbatim. I am quite perplexed as well.

Comment: @Hiws you're not exactly recreating the same. You're creating a new Array with the `filter()` function. @WoJ I'd still stick to the same. I guess you're just losing the object which you are referencing to. Again, I assume it's just a reference. Hence, that's the problem.

Comment: @Aer0 What do you mean I'm creating a new array with the `filter`? The only place i have a `filter` is in the computed property which is copy/pasted from the code above. The only thing I've changed is the `fetch` method from the example to my own `fetchData` method which returns a promise after a 2 second delay with the stringified JSON.

Comment: @Aer0: I just tried `this.tags = _.cloneDeep(r)` to make sure I have the clone and the result is the same.

Comment: That's strange. Would you mind setting up a small live example?

Comment: @Aer0: I found the issue (though it is strange). Note the `:click` instead of `@click` → by modifying that everything is back to normal. I have no idea how that (a bound property `click`) could have changed that much. I will delete the question i guess as it is more a typo than anything (though it is perplexing)

Comment: @Hiws I found the issue (though it is strange). Note the `:click` instead of `@click` → by modifying that everything is back to normal. I have no idea how that (a bound property `click`) could have changed that much. I will delete the question i guess as it is more a typo than anything (though it is perplexing)

Comment: Wow, I feel pretty stupid right now, overseen such a little detail ... however, happy you got that solved.

Comment: @Aer0: so you can imagine how stupid **I** feel :) I still do not understand why the impact was such but anyway - it works. Thank you.